# Python - Capitalize only first letter of each word in a string

Tags: python, regex, uppercase, capitalize

I want to check if the first character of first word is capitalized, if not, then capitalize it leaving rest of the string's casing intact.

I've tried the following method:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'((?<=[\.\?!]\s)(\w+)|(^\w+))')
def cap(match):
    return(match.group().capitalize())

p.sub(cap, 'CBH1 protein was analyzed. to evaluate the report')

>>> Output : Cbh1 protein was analyzed. To evaluate the report
```

While this output is nearly correct, I expect the initial *Cbh1* to be *CBH1*. Any suggestions?

Comment: The capitalize function doesn't know about abbreviations. How could it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a perfect match for any of the builtin `str` methods: `.title()` and `.capitalize()` will lowercase all letters after the first, while `.upper()` will capitalize everything.

It's not elegant, but you can just explicitly capitalize the first letter and append the rest:

```py
def cap(match):
    grp = match.group()
    return grp[0].upper() + grp[1:]

>>> p.sub(cap, 'CBH1 protein was analyzed. to evaluate the report')
'CBH1 protein was analyzed. To evaluate the report'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[a-z]\w*` instead of `\w+`. In this way you will match only the strings that really need to be capitalized.

I'd also fix the regex in this way:

```
(?:(?<=[.?!]\s)|^)[a-z]\w*
```